Java Selenium driver - Threads are not getting destroyed on driver.quit
I'm encountering some unusual issues with the Selenium driver in Java. Our application collects and stores data from the user interface using Selenium automation scripts. This automated process runs about 300 to 400 times per day, executing correctly and storing data in the database as expected.
However, after the Java service has been running for more than a week, it begins to throw the error "Unable to create a new thread," eventually leading to an out-of-memory exception on the server. To resolve this, I have to restart the Java service. After a restart, it works for a few more days before the same thread error and out-of-memory exception occur again.
Through debugging, I've observed that Selenium-related threads remain in the thread chain even after being closed with the driver.quit() statement in the finally block. Despite attempts to interrupt these threads, they persist, appearing as sleeping or zombie threads in the live threads list.
Has anyone faced similar issues or know of any fixes?
Java version: 17
Selenium version: 4.16.0
Selenium related thread should destroyed on driver.quit

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Even with basic chrome driver launch and quit will reproduce the thread issue. Threads details can be tracked through using JVisualVm or Jconsole.
